# Complete Development using the Motorola XOOM

Tags: android, compilation, device

I really want to get into Android programming but I only have access to company resources right now. I have the money right now to purchase a XOOM or a development laptop. Is it possible to compile Android apps using the command line on the Xoom while using other apps to write the program files.

What would seem like a dream environment would be if I purchased a XOOM and a BlueTooth Keyboard. Am I dreaming? Developing using older Android devices was naturally limited by the screen space of the device and the underlying hardware also.

Answer (score 6):

No, as far as I know, you cannot develop Android applications from within Android. You will need a Windows, Mac, or Linux desktop environment to develop Android applications. Visit the [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/index.html) site for additional info on the SDK.

Comment: Thanks. I will be getting the development laptop.

Answer (score 3):

Go for the development laptop, and test your applications on the [emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html). Initially you can get friends to test them out on their android for you, and hopefully by the time you make something important enough you will be able to afford your own android.

Comment: i believe this is the best answer

Comment: I already own an X. I just thought it would be cool to completely forego the PC world while programming. I'll be getting me the development laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en).  It can build and deploy apps natively on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't have a version of the SDK that runs on an android device, although as devices become more powerful this would be a pretty awesome thing to have.

You'll want the laptop, since it can emulate different android devices.

Comment: What is missing in the stack in order to enable this?

Comment: @user, the standard SDK isn't written or compiled to run on an Android device. Such usage is also not allowed according to the license agreement (unless you understand the "XOOM" to be a "Personal Computer"). The only one who can make it happen is Google.

Comment: Hmm.. The XOOM is a personal computer.  Screen, keyboard, processor, ports, wifi, operating system.

Comment: What's missing is the necessary tools (SDK, compilers, etc) for the XOOM's processor.

Comment: Why wouldn't Google want development for Google products to be done in a Google environment? Too much like that Fruit Company? lol

Comment: Ha ha.  Well, it'll be a long long time before you can develop straight on an iThing.  Apparently, apps aren't allowed to execute "arbitrary code"

Answer (score 0):

Buy the laptop and get a cheap phone on craigslists.

Although, the XOOM emulator doesn't work at all, so if you want to develop specifically for that tablet it's a good idea to buy it. It's impossible to emulate android 3.0 on any computer on earth :)

Comment: It's impossible on mine. Maybe on windows or linux it's just slow but on the mac it's broken. I have the last macbook pro with 8gb ram.

Comment: I was using an iMac, no idea of the model and hardware. But it DID work.

Comment: Yes, on my macbook pro tried once before. work well. but didn't explore much

Comment: android tablet emulator is a lie :)